# Mock redis for writing unittest for application

Tags: python, unit-testing, redis, pytest, flask-caching

I have a flask application, in which I use "flask-caching" with redis. I save some values in the cache and retrieve it for processing. I have to write unittest for this. How can I mock the redis instance and pass the host for that server in the flask caching config.

I did try "fakeredis", but that does not give me the redis host, which I can use in flask caching and test my application.

How can I go about writing unit test cases for this ?

```
def func_1():
    # some steps
    x = func2() # this is where the code for flask caching (redis) data retrieval is
    # process x
```

I have to test func_1()

Comment: Mock out the calls to redis and assert the correct methods were called on the mock

Comment: One of the functions I have to test have code related to flask caching for retrieving the data and processing it. So, I won't be able to write unit tests for that. Don't have different function to just retrieve redis data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [mock object library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#module-unittest.mock) can be used to create a [Mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) instance for Redis that [returns a value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) for a particular method call, for example:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock

def test_redis():
    mock_redis = Mock()
    mock_redis.get.return_value = "2020-12-31T00:00:00".encode()

    function_to_test(mock_redis)
```

If a function needs to be mocked, so that the function is not actually called, and is used inside the function that is being tested, the [patch decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch) can be used, as follows:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("package.module.function_to_mock")
def test_redis(mock_function_to_mock):
    mock_function_to_mock.get.return_value = "2020-12-31T00:00:00".encode()

    function_to_test()
```

This could be used to mock the flask caching related code that is inside the function that you are testing.

---

**Edit**

For your case, I believe you may want to do the following:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("package.module.func2")
def test_func_1(mock_func2):
    mock_func2.return_value = "Test value"

    func_1()

    mock_func2.assert_called_once()
```

Here `func2()` is mocked and it's return value is set to `"Test value"`, so when it is called inside of `func_1()` variable `x` equals `"Test value"`

> Note: the path passed to `patch()` must be to where `func2()` is imported, and not to the module where `func2()` is defined.

Comment: Can you pls. explain the difference between function_to_mock and mock_function_to_mock in the second example ?

Comment: @Simplecode `function_to_mock` is the target function to mock, so that it's not actually called. I believe for your case `function_to_mock` is `func2()`. `mock_function_to_mock` is the `MagicMock` instance created by `patch()` for `function_to_mock`. In other words, `patch()` replaces `function_to_mock` with a `MagicMock` instance, which is then passed to the test function `test_redis()` via the `mock_function_to_mock` parameter. `mock_function_to_mock` can then be used to specify returned values.

Comment: Is this necessary to use ```mock_func2.assert_called_once() ? ```

Comment: @Simplecode It's not necessary to call `mock_func2.assert_called_once()` as it only checks that `func2` is called only once inside of `func_1()`. If you don't want to check this, then it can be left out.